# MongoDb 4.0.5 issue - Updating array field items from string to int inside a collection by converting values from string to int not working

Tags: mongodb

I have the test collection of following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5efc8285d573109c093229fe"),   
    "units" : [ 
        {
            "keyword_id" : "44",            
            "rating" : {
                "exact_rating" : {
                    "rating" : "55"
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "keyword_id" : "45",
            "rating" : {
                "exact_rating" : {
                    "rating" : "43",
                    "sample-field": "Yes"
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "rating" : {
                "exact_rating" : {
                    "rating" : 1,
                    "sample-field": "No"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "result_id" : 111,  
};
```

I need to convert the values of rating field from `string` inside the units array (`units.rating.exact_rating.rating`) into `integer` and also remove any other field inside the object such as `sample-field`. I'm trying to use the `update()` function with `forEach()` and trying to use the `set()` method using the following query but it is not working:

```
db.getCollection('test').find().forEach(function(res)
{    
    print( "Id: " + res._id );
    db.getCollection('test').update(
      { "units.rating.exact_rating" : { $exists: true }},
      { $set: { "units.$[].rating.exact_rating": {"rating": res.units.rating.exact_rating.rating}} },
      { multi: true })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing that with a for loop will require returning the entire collection, over the network, modifying it locally, and then sending it back over the network to save.

You could accomplish those tasks on the server side with an aggregation pipeline, and use $out stage to save the documents in a temporary collection.  After everything is modified, you could then drop the original collection and rename the temporary one to replace it.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {
      units: {
        $map: {
          input: "$units",
          as: "unit",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$unit",
              {rating: {
                  exact_rating: {
                    rating: {
                      $convert: {
                        input: "$$unit.rating.exact_rating.rating",
                        to: "int",
                        onError: {
                          badRating: "$$unit.rating.exact_rating.rating"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
              }}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
  }},
  {$out: "temp_collection"}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bWA9S4G7EKJ)